# Why are my axes not positioning over my bar chart in this d3.js graph?

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a project to teach myself d3.js where I'm building a bar graph using an API of US GDP. However, now that I've added my axes, the axes place where I expected them to. However, they have pushed my bars down below them. Can anyone explain to me why my axes and bars are behaving this way, and what I can do to fix this?

```js
let apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json"

GDPGraph ()


function GDPGraph () {
    fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // document.getElementById('GDP').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.data);

        var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            height = document.documentElement.clientHeight * .8,
            margin = 10;
    
        var GDPbyQuarter = [],
            yearQuarter =[]

        const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
            GDPbyQuarter.push(data.data[i][1])
        }

        for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
            yearQuarter.push(data.data[i][0])
        }

        console.log(yearQuarter)

        // console.log('calculated width:',((1/GDPbyQuarter.length)*width),'calculated legnth:', GDPbyQuarter.length, 'total width:', width)

        const maxNumber = d3.max(GDPbyQuarter)
    
        console.log(maxNumber);
    
        const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, GDPGraph.length])
        .range([0, width]);
    
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, maxNumber])
        .range([0, height]);
    
    
        d3.select('body')
            .selectAll('div')
            .data(GDPbyQuarter)
            .enter() 
            .append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .style('height', (d) => yScale(d)+'px')
            .style('width', ((1/(GDPbyQuarter.length+margin)*width)+'px'))
            .append('title')
            .attr('class', 'title')
            .text((d, i) => yearQuarter[i]+': ' + d)
            
       
        
        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

        svg.append("g")
        .call(xAxis)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height -100) + ")");
        


        svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(10,0)')
        .call(yAxis)
    })
}
```

```css
.bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    
  }

.bar:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.title {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>US GDP By Quarter</h1>
        <h3>FreeCodeCamp</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="GDP">
        
    </div>

    
    <script src='js/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an `svg` node for each bar. Try inspecting the DOM using the Chrome Dev tools

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to fix my positioning. I ended up making the containing div position:relative; and then my elements within the div position:absolute;

```
#GDP {
position: relative;
}

#GDP > * {
    position: absolute;
}

g {
    position: absolute;
}
```